# Rails 4 Unknown Format error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to create a user but when I submit it I get the error. I set json as the default format in the users controller and in my routes, however I still get this error. Im running Rails 4.2.2 and ruby 2.2.1

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):


Users Controller 

class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    respond_with User.find(params[:id])
  end
  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      render json: user, status: 201, location: [:api, user]
    else
      render json: { errors: user.errors }, status: 422
    end
  end
  def update
    user = User.find(params[:id])

    if user.update(user_params)
        render json: user, status: 200, location: [:api, user]
    else
        render json: { errors: user.errors }, status: 422
    end
  end
  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    user.destroy
    head 204
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Routes

```
require 'api_constraints'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json },
                              constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/'  do
    scope module: :v1,
              constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      resources :users, :only => [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
    end
  end
end
```

Log

```
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"example@gmail.com"}, "registration"=>{"user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"pilon24@icloud.com"}}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
MONGODB | Adding localhost:27017 to the cluster.
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | quickalertapi_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{"email"=>"example@gmail.com"}, "projection"=>{"_id"=>1}, "limit"=>1}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | quickalertapi_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.044546s
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | quickalertapi_development.insert | STARTED | {"insert"=>"users", "documents"=>[{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('57570c29dd4736cc49ddcdfc'), "email"=>"example@gmail.com", "encrypted_password"=>"$2a$11$1NFccmBD10pUW59b2TQ.9ezJPQkmdnrBoEzaq/Sdl9T5K7miH62/a", "sign_in_count"=>0, "updated_at"=>2016-06-07 18:...
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | quickalertapi_development.insert | SUCCEEDED | 0.009481999999999999s
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | quickalertapi_development.update | STARTED | {"update"=>"users", "updates"=>[{"q"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('57570c29dd4736cc49ddcdfc')}, "u"=>{"$set"=>{"last_sign_in_at"=>2016-06-07 18:02:17 UTC, "current_sign_in_at"=>2016-06-07 18:02:17 UTC, "last_sign_in_ip"=>"127.0.0.1", "current_sign_in_ip"=>...
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | quickalertapi_development.update | SUCCEEDED | 0.012626s
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 371ms



ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  responders (2.2.0) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:207:in `respond_with'
  devise (4.1.1) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:23:in `create'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:553:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:84:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  /Users/Phil/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:155:in `handle'
  /Users/Phil/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:109:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in start'
  /Users/Phil/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in start'
  /Users/Phil/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:96:in `each'
  /Users/Phil/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:96:in `block in start'
  /Users/Phil/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:76:in `loop'
  /Users/Phil/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:76:in `start'
  /Users/Phil/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:12:in `run'
  /Users/Phil/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/bin/nack_worker:4:in `<main>'


  Rendered /Users/Phil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (5.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/Phil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/Phil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/Phil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (115.4ms)
```

Comment: Can you provide the error stack trace as well ?

Comment: So the error is coming from a different controller (RegistrationController) rather the one that you have provided. You seem to be sending a json request to a controller that [does not](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) support it.

Comment: ohh devise is receiving the request not my users controller thank you for noticing